# Ubuntu is slow. Is it due to 2 OS's?

Tags: dual-boot

I have been running Ubuntu 12.10 in it's own partition for dual-boot with Windows 7 for a week now.

Would running Ubuntu like this make it run slower? Would it be faster if I installed Ubuntu over Windows 7 and have it as my only OS?

What's running slow? Opening a video file in vlc player (800MB/4GB file) takes at least 3 seconds. Extracting files takes much longer than doing with winrar in Windows.

My laptop has an i3 with 4GB RAM.

Thanks for your time.

(currently I'm still deciding between the 2 OS's)

Comment: Running as a dual boot should not impact the speed (as opposed to something like installing in Windows with Wubi), so installing over Windows would not make it faster.

I notice similar behaviour with VLC, not sure why. You could try another media player, like smplayer which I notice is a bit snappier. Also, if it is due to VLC loading components then perhaps installing preload may help.

Comment: @mvario please stop posting answers as comments. Either answer the question or refrain :)

Answer (score 1):

Dual booting Ubuntu with Windows does not make Ubuntu run any slower, so installing Ubuntu over Windows 7 would not make it run faster (at least not appreciably faster). If Ubuntu was running inside Windows in a VM or wubi, it would run slower because your processor would have to tell Windows 7 what to tell Ubuntu, and Ubuntu would have to tell Windows 7 what to tell your processor. It's like trying to have a conversation with someone through another person - it's going to take longer.

Since you have Ubuntu running in its own partition though, it is talking directly to your processor without going through Windows.